# miktex-makemf - The t1xtt source file could not be found

Tags: miktex

I have updated today (2021/12/10) Ubuntu 20.04 which included an updated library of miktex.
As a result, now I have the following error (from log file) when trying to compile a fully functional .tex file:

miktex-makemf - The t1xtt source file could not be found

Any help on how to resolve this issue?

Thank you very much in advance

I do not have a test case. I just took the coversheet of the document that gave me that error and also gives me error but a different one:

> 2021-12-10 17:08:04,266+0100 INFO  miktex-makemf - this process (7590)
> started by 'miktex-makepk' with command line: miktex-makemf
> --miktex-enable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --miktex-disable-diagnose --verbose rtxptmr 2021-12-10 17:08:04,267+0100 FATAL miktex-makemf - The rtxptmr source file could
> not be found. 2021-12-10 17:08:04,267+0100 FATAL miktex-makemf - The
> rtxptmr source file could not be found. 2021-12-10 17:08:04,267+0100
> FATAL miktex-makemf - Info:  2021-12-10 17:08:04,267+0100 FATAL
> miktex-makemf - Source:  2021-12-10 17:08:04,267+0100 FATAL
> miktex-makemf - Line: 0 2021-12-10 17:08:04,268+0100 INFO
> miktex-makemf - this process (7590) finishes with exit code 1

This is the .tex that gives this second error:
Here you have a small .tex that gives me the another error (this is my PhD thesis coversheet):

```
%----------
%   WARNING
%----------

% 
% This Guide contains Library recommendations based mainly on APA and IEEE styles (https://uc3m.libguides.com/en/thesis/), but you must always follow the guidelines of your thesis Tutor and the rules and regulations of the Doctoral School.

%----------
%   DOCUMENT SETTINGS
%----------

\documentclass[12pt]{report} % font: 12pt

% MÁRGENES: 2,5 cm top an bottom; 3 cm left and right
\usepackage[
a4paper,
vmargin=2.5cm,
hmargin=3cm
]{geometry}

% Paragraph Spacing and Line Spacing: Narrow (6 pt / 1.15 spacing) or Moderate (6 pt / 1.5 spacing)
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}
\parskip=6pt

% PDF/A -- Important for its inclusion in e-Archive. PDF/A is the optimal format for preservation and for the generation of metadata: http://uc3m.libguides.com/ld.php?content_id=31389625. 

% In the template we include the file OUTPUT.XMPDATA. You can download that file and include the metadata that will be incorporated into the PDF file when you compile the memoria.tex file. Then upload it back to your project.   
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}

% LINKS
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black, % links to parts of the document (e.g. index) in black
    urlcolor=blue} % links to resources outside the document in blue
\usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption} %Remove line between figure and captio

% MATH EXPRESSIONS
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}

% Character encoding
\usepackage{txfonts} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs} 

% Nomenclature
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

%Algorithms
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx


% English settings
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[babel, english=american]{csquotes}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\small}

% Footer settings
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}

% DESIGN OF THE TITLES of the parts of the work (chapters and epigraphs or sub-chapters)
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\large\bfseries\filcenter}
{\thechapter.}
{5pt}
{\MakeUppercase}
{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{*3}
\titlecontents{chapter}
[0pt]                                               
{}
{\contentsmargin{0pt}\thecontentslabel.\enspace\uppercase}
{\contentsmargin{0pt}\uppercase}                        
{\titlerule*[.7pc]{.}\contentspage}                 

\titleformat{\section}
{\bfseries}
{\thesection.}
{5pt}
{}
\titlecontents{section}
[5pt]                                               
{}
{\contentsmargin{0pt}\thecontentslabel.\enspace}
{\contentsmargin{0pt}}
{\titlerule*[.7pc]{.}\contentspage}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalsize\bfseries}
{\thesubsection.}
{5pt}
{}
\titlecontents{subsection}
[10pt]                                               
{}
{\contentsmargin{0pt}                          
    \thecontentslabel.\enspace}
{\contentsmargin{0pt}}                        
{\titlerule*[.7pc]{.}\contentspage}  

% Footnotes
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}

% FIGURES
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{imagenes/}} % Images folder

%REFERENCES 

% IEEE bibliography setup
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=ieee, isbn=false,sortcites, maxbibnames=6, minbibnames=1]{biblatex} % Setting for IEEE citation style, recommended for engineering. "maxbibnames" indicates that from 6 authors truncate the list in the first one (minbibnames) and add "et al." as used in the IEEE style.
%\addbibresource{bibliography/thesisRefLibrary.bib}  % The references.bib file in which the bibliography used should be

%-------------
%   DOCUMENT
%-------------

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman} % Roman numerals are used in the numbering of the pages preceding the body of the work.
%----------
%   COVER
%---------- 
\begin{titlepage}
    %\begin{sffamily}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{Huge}
            xxxxx\\         
            \bigskip
            by\\
            \bigskip
            xxxx\\
        \end{Huge}
        \vspace{3 cm}   
        \begin{Large}
            A dissertation submitted by in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of Doctor of Philosophy in\\
            \bigskip
            xxxx\\
            \vspace{2cm}
            xxxxx\\
            \vspace{3cm}
            Advisor(s):\\
            \bigskip
            xxxxx\\
            \bigskip
            Tutor:\\
            \bigskip
            xxxxx\\
            \bigskip
            XXXXX 202X\\
         \end{Large}
         
    \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}
    
%----------
%   LICENCIA CREATIVE COMMONS
%---------- 
%\input{License/License.tex}    

%----------
%   DEDICATION
%---------- 
%\input{Dedication/Dedication.tex}

%----------
%   DECLARATION
%---------- 
%\input{Declaration/Declaration.tex}

%----------
%   ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS
%---------- 
% If you do not wish any acknowledgements to your thesis, do not include this page.
%\input{Acknowledgement/Acknowledgement.tex}

%----------
%   PUBLISHED AND SUBMITTED CONTENT
%---------- 
%\input{Publishment/Publishment.tex}

%----------
%   OTHER RESEARCH MERITS
%---------- 
%\input{OtherMerits/OtherMerits.tex}

%--
% Nomenclature
%--
% See https://bytefreaks.net/applications/using-nomenclature-in-texstudio
\printnomenclature
\thispagestyle{fancy}
%----------
%   TOC
%---------- 
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{fancy}

%--
% List of figures. If they are not included, comment the following lines
%-
\listoffigures
\thispagestyle{fancy}

%--
% List of tables. If they are not included, comment the following lines
%-
\listoftables
\thispagestyle{fancy}

%----------
%   THESIS
%---------- 
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic} % % numbering with Arabic numerals for the rest of the document. 
%----------
%   THESIS
%---------- 
\pagenumbering{arabic} % % numbering with Arabic numerals for the rest of the document. 

%\clearpage \input{Chapter1/chapter1.tex}
%\clearpage \input{Chapter2/chapter2.tex}
%\clearpage \input{Chapter3/chapter3.tex}
%\clearpage \input{Chapter4/chapter4.tex}
%\clearpage \input{Chapter5/chapter5.tex}
%\clearpage \input{Chapter6/chapter6.tex}
%\clearpage \input{Chapter7/chapter7.tex}

\clearpage \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
% BibTeX users please use one of
%\bibliographystyle{spbasic}      % basic style, author-year citations
%\bibliographystyle{spmpsci}      % mathematics and physical sciences
%\bibliographystyle{spphys}       % APS-like style for physics
%\printbibliography 
\clearpage{}

%----------
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you asked the support of MiKteX on the MikTeX homepage?

Comment: Show a small but complete example that can be used for a test.

Comment: I finally found the solution. I opened the MikTex Console in Ubuntu 20.04 and I noticed that there were 93 updates pending. I just updated everything and now it works.